# Swift, NWConnection UDP receive timeout?

Tags: swift, udp, timeout

My app send message to server then wait for reply, over udp. But there are random packet loss.

I want to detect packet loss by timeout, how can I do it in swift?
I cannot find it from doc.

Comment: You would need to start a `Timer`.  If the response arrives before the timer fires, cancel the timer.  If the timer fires, you know there was a timeout

Comment: Why wouldn't apple provide such basic feature.....

Comment: Because UDP is connectionless and best effort delivery. As a consequence, there is no concept of a timeout in UDP. If you want to build delivery response into your protocol to try and make it more reliable, that is up to you. This isn't an Apple thing, no UDP implementation can provide an inbuilt  timeout as such a concept doesn't make sense with UDP. If you want reliability and connection orientation, use TCP

Comment: Now I think of it, given UDP is designed to be unreliable, why the default behaviour of receive() is to wait indefinitely for something that is unreliable?

Comment: That isn't related to unreliability. The idea is you execute a receive and at some point it completes and you process that data. If it had a timeout you would probably just need to submit a new receive anyway and there is a chance that the packet could arrive between the receive timing out and you submitting another. It's not like the pending receive consumes any CPU